# xampp unable to determine IP address of

Tags: php, xampp

I want to run php file in xampp

I must use php for hackers-on, but xampp will not work at all providing error messages, which:

### xampp manager/osx

```
Foos-MBP proftpd[67104]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'Foos-MBP'
Foos-MBP proftpd[67104]: error: no valid servers configured
Foos-MBP proftpd[67104]: Fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

I saw this issues

[ubuntu proftpd[5291]: warning: unable to determine IP address of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434364/ubuntu-proftpd5291-warning-unable-to-determine-ip-address-of)

### Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf

and tried to add 
`DefaultAdress http://localhost/`
But returned error that:

```
Foos-MBP proftpd[67547]: Fatal: unknown configuration directive 'DefaultAdress' on line 36 of '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

### etc/hosts

in`/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
192.168.0.19    team-a1.2021.local
```

tried
[XAMPP , PROFTPD problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587555/xampp-proftpd-problems)
and updated my `etc/hosts` as:
`127.0.0.1  Foos-MBP.local`
But it cause nothing....

### hostname

`hostname`: returns

```
FOOs-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Please tell me what to do (><)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting hostname worked....
Re writing `127.0.0.1   localhost`
to `127.0.0.1  Foos-MBP.local`

Comment: Your original solution of modifying /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf was correct, but the directive is "DefaultA**dd**ress", not "DefaultA**d**ress" — just a typo.

So this should work just fine (in proftpd.conf):

`DefaultAddress 127.0.0.1`